# Compare Excel columns to identify numerical values contained in one but not the other

Tags: excel

I have three columns of numerical values in Excel:

Column A contains 2444 numerical values

Column B contains 2838 numerical values. I have entered the following formula in cell C2 to remove leading zeroes of the numerical values and output the result to Column C:
=VALUE(TRIM(CLEAN(B2:B2839)))

Column C contains 2838 numerical values with leading zeroes removed

I want to compare the 2444 numerical values in Column A against the 2838 numerical values in Column C to identify the numerical values that are contained in Column A but not contained in Column C

I have explored conditional formatting rules on Excel but haven't been able to determine which would be appropriate.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: in column d: `=countif(A:A, C2)` and copy down. If you find a `0` then that value in column A is not present in column C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have spill range, if you put this formula in a cell that can spill down, you'll get a distinct list of every cell in column `A` that does not exist in column `C`

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,NOT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A:A,C:C,0)))*(A:A<>"")))
```

[Example with Google sheets.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12IAi7BSbwVJHN2CZjKZF2yhtcqj84QNHeCx0G-9PryA/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0):

Put a column next to A that has all X's. Then just do a vlookup using the values in B and bring in the X's. If a value doesn't have an X, it's not on list A. Or vice versa if that's applicable.